# Salesforce Knowledge

Tags: knowledge, servicecloud

[image]I am not able to see the "Information" window when I look at knowledge in my developer org. Am I missing a permission?

I can only see

Title
URL Name
Summary
Validation Status

Without the information window I am only able to create summaries.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: John can you be more specific and precise .You want article management tab?What do you mean by information window?

Comment: I added a picture from Salesforce's documentation.

Comment: you will need to add data into the rich text field to help you .Thanks

Comment: I don't get the rich text field box. I dont see anything below that blue line on the picture. That picture is from the salesforce documentation.

Comment: Thanks Mohith. A colleague figured out what to do. I appreciate your help. I just needed to add a rich text field to the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had not added the rich text field to my article layout.